# Include dynamically loaded DLL in ASP.NET shadow copy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a .NET 4.8 WCF web service C# project. The project has a dependency on a NuGet package (MongoDB driver) that dynamically loads an unmanaged DLL at runtime. The WCF project is configured with [`<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="true" />`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.hostingenvironmentsection.shadowcopybinassemblies?view=netframework-4.8.1), which means that the project's binaries get copied to a directory like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b7a5a506\12f9e2ba\assembly\dl3\1c0dc8f9\00927575_ae94d901`, where IIS loads them from.

The MongoDB library tries to load the unmanaged DLL from the same directory as the library's managed DLL. But it is unable to find it, as the unmanaged DLL isn't shadow copied. Is there a way to configure my project to shadow copy the unmanaged DLL alongside the library's managed DLL? Or is there another way to work around this, other than disabling shadow copying?

Comment: Since **<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="true" />** locks the assembly, and the unmanaged dll cannot be called directly, it cannot copy the unmanaged dll file. You can try to copy the unmanaged dll file directly to the relevant folder using **CopyTo** and streaming.